# How to send variables to class methods

Tags: c++

I have some variables in my program that are actually in a case statement.  I have tried to get them to go to my class functions but I keep getting an error.  I am suppose to get the variables to go to the SalariedEmployee and the Administrator class.

```cpp
//Lynette Wilkins
//Week 12

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

class SalariedEmployee
{
private:
    double wageRate;
    int hours;
protected:
    string name;
    string ssn;
    double netPay;
    string department;

public:
    SalariedEmployee(string n, string s, double np, double w, int h, string d);
     ~SalariedEmployee() {cout<<endl;}
     string Getname();  //returns name
     string Getssn();   // returns social security number
     double GetnetPay(); //returns netPay
     string Getdepartment(); // returns department
     double GetwageRate(); //returns wage rate
     int Gethours(); //returns hours
     void Setname(string); //sets name
     void Setssn(string); //sets ssn
     void SetnetPay(double); //sets net pay
     void Setdepartment(string); //sets department
     void SetwageRate(double); //sets wage rate
     void Sethours(int); //sets hours

};


string SalariedEmployee::Getname()
{
    return name;
}

string SalariedEmployee::Getssn()
{
    return ssn;
}

double SalariedEmployee::GetnetPay()
{
    return netPay;
}

double SalariedEmployee::GetwageRate()
{
    return wageRate;
}

int SalariedEmployee::Gethours()
{
    return hours;
}
void SalariedEmployee::Setname(string n)
{
    name = n;

}

void SalariedEmployee::Setssn(string s)
{
    ssn = s;
}

void SalariedEmployee::SetnetPay(double np)
{
    netPay = np;
}

void SalariedEmployee::Setdepartment(string d)
{
    department = d;
}


void SalariedEmployee::SetwageRate(double w)
{
    wageRate = w;
}

void SalariedEmployee::Sethours(int h)
{
    hours = h;
}


class Administrator : public SalariedEmployee
{
protected:
    string title;
    string responsi;
    string super;
    double salary;
public:
    Administrator(string t, string r, string s, double sa);
     ~Administrator();
    string Gettitle();
    string Getresponsi();
    string Getsuper();
    double Getsalary();
    void Settitle(string);
    void Setresponsi(string);
    void Setsuper(string);
    void Setsalary(double);
    void print();
};

Administrator::~Administrator()
{
    cout<<endl;
}

string Administrator::Gettitle()
{
    return title;
}

string Administrator::Getresponsi()
{
    return responsi;
}

string Administrator::Getsuper()
{
    return super;
}

double Administrator::Getsalary()
{
    return salary;
}
void Administrator::Settitle(string ti)
{
    title = ti;
}
void Administrator::Setresponsi(string re)
{
    responsi = re;
}


void Administrator::Setsuper(string su)
{
    super=su;
}

void Administrator::Setsalary(double sa)
{
    salary= sa;
}

void Administrator::print( )
  {

    cout << "\n_______________________________________________\n";

    cout << "Pay to the order of " << name<< endl;
    cout << "The sum of " << netPay << " Dollars\n";
    cout << "_________________________________________________\n";
    cout <<endl<<endl;
    cout << "Employee Number: " << ssn << endl;
    cout << "Salaried Employee. Regular Pay: " 
       << salary << endl; 
    cout << "_________________________________________________\n";
  }





int main()
{


    string name;
    string soc;
    double net = 0;
    double wage = 0;
    int hrs = 0;
    string dept;
    string admtitle;
    string resp;
    string sup;
    double sal = 0;
    int response;

    string date = "January 12, 2013";


    cout<<setprecision(2)
    <<setiosflags(ios::fixed)
    <<setiosflags(ios::showpoint);

    SalariedEmployee emp1(name, soc,net, wage, hrs, dept);


while(response != 4){

    cout<<"Employee and Administrator Salary Program "<<endl;
    cout<<"(You will have to enter data first before you do anything else)"<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<"Enter Employee Data,  Enter 1"<<endl;
    cout<<"Change data,   Enter 2"<<endl;
    cout<<"Print Check,   Enter 3"<<endl;
    cout<<"End Program, Enter 4"<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<"Please make your selection"<<endl;



cin>> response;

    switch (response)


    {
    case 1:
        cout <<"The employee's data will be entered here: "<<endl<<endl;

        cout<<"Enter the employees name: ";
        cin.ignore();
        getline(cin, name);

        cout<<"Enter the employees social security number: ";
         cin.ignore();
        getline(cin, soc);

        cout<<"Enter the employees net pay: ";
        cin>>net;

        cout<<"Enter the employees wage rate: ";
        cin>>wage;

        cout<<"Enter the number of hours the employer worked: ";
        cin>>hrs;

        cout<<"Enter the employees title: ";
        cin.ignore();
        getline(cin,admtitle);

        cout<<"Enter the employees area responsibility: ";
        cin.ignore();
        getline(cin, resp);

        cout<<"Enter the employees salary: ";
        cin>>sal;



        cout<<endl<<endl<<endl;


        break;




    case 2:

        cout<<"Please change the data you entered previously here. " <<endl<<endl;

        cout<<"Enter the employees name: ";
        cin.ignore();
        getline(cin, name);

        cout<<"Enter the employees social security number: ";
         cin.ignore();
        getline(cin, soc);

        cout<<"Enter the employees net pay: ";
        cin>>net;

        cout<<"Enter the employees wage rate: ";
        cin>>wage;

        cout<<"Enter the number of hours the employer worked: ";
        cin>>hrs;

        cout<<"Enter the employees title: ";
        cin.ignore();
        getline(cin,admtitle);

        cout<<"Enter the employees area responsibility: ";
        cin.ignore();
        getline(cin, resp);

        cout<<"Enter the employees salary: ";
        cin>>sal;



        cout<<endl<<endl<<endl;
break;



    case 3:

        cout <<"Information Printed"<<endl<<endl;

        cout<<"_____________________________"<<date<<endl;
        &Administrator::print;



        break;


    default:

        cout<<endl<<endl
            <<"Invalid Selection! Try Again"<<endl;
        exit(1);

}
}





    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What "error" are you "getting"?

Comment: main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall SalariedEmployee::SalariedEmployee(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,double,double,int,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)" (??0SalariedEmployee@@QAE@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@0NNH0@Z) referenced in function _main
1> fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

Comment: That link error indicates that your code is not defining the SalariedEmployee::SalariedEmployee() method (i.e. the constructor).

Answer (score 2):

You never defined the constructors for SalariedEmployee or Administrator.  Another answerer showed how you might define an implementation of a constructor that matches the signature in your existing definition, but in your code, the values of those variables are meaningless when you instantiate the `emp1` object anyway, so you'd do better to just use a default constructor where you simply initialize most variables to 0:

```
SalariedEmployee::SalariedEmployee() :
    wageRate(0), hours(0), netPay(0) {}
```

Note that I didn't bother initializing the `string` members; they automatically initialize themselves to "" (nothing).

Also, when you input data with `getline()`, you're not doing anything with it.  Call one of your setter functions to pass the value that you read from `getline(cin,...)` to your emp1 object.  Your option '3' looks like it's supposed to print whatever you entered previously, but you're not calling any "print" function.  Your code has `&Administrator::print;` but that doesn't print anything.  That statement evaluates to the address of the `print` method of the `Administrator` class, but you don't do anything with that address, so that statement does nothing.  You might want to call `emp1.print()`, but `emp1` is an object of type `SalariedEmployee`, not `Administrator`, and there's no `print()` method in the `SalariedEmployee` class.

Has your class talked about virtual inheritance (polymorphism)?  If so, then you're probably supposed to be declaring a `print()` method in your `SalariedEmployee` class, and then defining an implementation of it in `Administrator`.  So in `class SalariedEmployee`, you'll want this:

```
void print() = 0;
```

Then, in `class Administrator`, define it just as you've done.  But when you create your `emp1` object, be sure to make its type be `Administrator` because `SalariedEmployee` is just an abstract base class (since you only declared that objects of types inherited from `SalariedEmployee` should have a print() method, but print() isn't actually defined in the `SalariedEmployee` class).

Comment: See well that is where I am confused because I thought once I asked the user for the data it went here -->  SalariedEmployee emp1(name, soc,net, wage, hrs, dept);-->  and the constructor was defined.

Comment: @CarlaBridgesWilkins, It was declared, but not defined. Anyway, in order for what you thought to happen, your class would have to store references as its data members, which would be a very bad solution. Instead, the constructor typically copies the data you give it into the class, or sets the members based on it, without actually copying it (e.g. `std::vector` taking a size and setting its data to have that many value-initialized elements).

Comment: @CarlaBridgesWilkins - Nothing in the code where you're asking the user for data tells the system to put the user's responses into the `emp1` object.  AH!  I SEE where your misconception is:  The constructor call doesn't tie the variables `name`, `soc`, `net`, etc. to the `emp1` object for all eternity; it merely passes the *current* values of those variables to the object's constructor.  If those values later change, those changes don't get passed on to the `emp1` object.  You have to pass them on yourself, by calling, for example, `emp1.Setname(name);`

Comment: @CarlaBridgesWilkins - And as Chris mentions, you COULD write you code to tie those variables to the emp1 object for all time by making the `SalariedEmployee` class hold references to variables passed in on the constructor, but that's generally not a good idea.  There are cases where that does make sense, but it's usually (not always) not good design in general.

Comment: OHHH ok, I understand now.  I was a little confused about defined and declared :)  Thanks for straightening that up for me.  OK.  I'm still working on it and its coming along.  I'm working on passing the variables to the Administrator right now and that is not working out so good for me.  I obviously have this wrong

Comment: @CarlaBridgesWilkins - How's it coming along?

Comment: Thanks for asking phonetagger.  I am still not getting these variables to pass. I don't know what the problem is. I am just not understanding how to code it to make it work  .....Administrator::Administrator(string t, string r, string s, double sa) :  title(t), responsi(r), super(s), salary(sa)
{
}

Comment: @CarlaBridgesWilkins - If you're calling a constructor that takes all of those arguments, keep in mind that it's taking *arguments*, not becoming the owner of the variables.  When you call the constructor and indicate variables in its calling arguments, the compiler takes the current values of those variables and passes them as arguments (parameters) to the constructor function.  It doesn't somehow tie those variables to the object you're constructing, it's just taking the values of the variables, not the variables themselves.  Instead of specifying, for example, `net` in the call to the...

Comment: ...constructor, you could instead simply pass the hard-coded value `36000` (not a variable).  So passing the variables' values to the constructor is not going to make the object somehow able to magically get new values when you read in a value for it.  You'll have to call a setter method on the `emp1` object when you want to change the value of something in the object.  So, for example, after reading in a value for `net`, then you'll need to call `emp1.Setnetpay(net);` to pass the value on to the `emp1` object.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't implement the constructor of SalariedEmployee. You need something like:

```
SalariedEmployee::SalariedEmployee(string n, string s, double np,
                                   double w, int h, string d)
    : name(n),
      ssn(s),
      netPay(np),
      wageRate(w),
      hours(h),
      department(d)
{
}
```

Comment: OOOOOH!!! ok let me look back in the program then